# Flatten object using auto mapper but not using ForMember or the naming conventions used for flattening

Tags: c#, automapper

Problem

Flatten large, multi level object using auto mapper to allow me to pass values to sql using Dapper.

Options

After reading the docs and various answers on SO, there seems to be two options, using `ForMember` or using NamingConventions. Neither of these can work for me as the object is so large that `ForMember` would require almost as much manual mapping. NamingConventions would mean some unreadable and irrelevant names for where the target object is being used.

refs I used: [ForMember](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Inline-Mapping.html?highlight=forMember) [flattening](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Flattening.html)

I did find a really basic example of using the `ITypeConverter` ([Custom type converters](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-type-converters.html)) and have tried to make it work for me, but I'm really struggling, after three days of trying, I thought I should turn for help.

After searching various forums I decided to try and create a generic solution as I will be reusing this multiple times throughout my project.

Please note, if there is a better way (an existing extension, or a configuration i've missed, i'd love to hear of it. If not could you please offer some guidance on how to complete my task - I feel like I'm banging my head against a brick wall)

below I have added the console app I created to try to resolve this (I feel I should say that I know this code is awful, I have just been hacking away in the hope something would work)

```
using AutoMapper;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace AutomapperTests
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var property = Program.CreateProperty();
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<PropertyDto, FlatProperty>()
                                                           .ConvertUsing<MyTypeConverter<PropertyDto, FlatProperty>>());

            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

            var flatProperty = mapper.Map<FlatProperty>(property);

        }

        private static PropertyDto CreateProperty()
        {
            var property = new PropertyDto();
            property.Guid = new Guid();//not mapping to guid
            property.SomeTestVal = 123456;
            property.TransactionStatus = TransactionStatus.ForSale;
            property.Address = new AddressDto();
            property.Detail = new DetailDto();
            property.Address.PostCode1 = "ng10";
            property.Detail.LandArea = 12;
            return property;
        }
    }

    public class MyTypeConverter<T, TK> : ITypeConverter<T, TK>
    {
        public TK Convert(T source, TK destination, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            var sourceType = source.GetType();
            PropertyInfo[] sourceClassProperties = sourceType.GetProperties();//note: i've tried flattening the structure at this point but failed

            var properties = GetCustomObjectsFromProperties(sourceType.GetProperties());

            destination = (TK)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TK));

            var destinationType = destination.GetType();
            PropertyInfo[] destinationProperties = destinationType.GetProperties();

            foreach (PropertyInfo sourceClassProperty in sourceClassProperties)
            {
                SetValue(sourceClassProperty, source, destinationProperties, destination);
            }

            return destination;
        }

        private void SetValue(PropertyInfo sourceClassProperty, T source, PropertyInfo[] destinationProperties, TK destination)
        {
            bool isNativeClass = IsNativeClass(sourceClassProperty);

            object sourceValue = sourceClassProperty.GetValue(source);
            string sourceName = sourceClassProperty.Name;

            PropertyInfo destProperty = destinationProperties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == sourceName);

            if (destProperty == null && !isNativeClass)
            {
                //note: my idea was to use recursion to enter the object if necessary and search for a matching value ---maybe i'm really overthinking this???
            }

            SetDestinationValue(destProperty, destination, sourceValue);
        }

        private bool IsNativeClass(PropertyInfo sourceClassProperty)
        {
            return sourceClassProperty.GetType().Namespace == "System";
        }

        private void SetDestinationValue(PropertyInfo destProperty, TK destination, object sourceValue)
        {
            if (destProperty != null)
            {
                destProperty.SetValue(destination, sourceValue);
            }
        }

        private PropertyInfo[] GetCustomObjectsFromProperties(PropertyInfo[] propertyInfo)
        {
            return propertyInfo.Where(info => info.Module.Name == GetAssemblyName()).ToArray();
        }

        private string GetAssemblyName()
        {
            return $"{typeof(T).Assembly.GetName().Name}.dll";
        }
    }

    public class FlatProperty
    {
        public Guid Guid { get; set; }
        public int SomeTestVal { get; set; }
        public int? TransactionStatusId { get; set; }
        public string Postcode1 { get; set; }
        public decimal? LandArea { get; set; }
    }

    public class PropertyDto
    {
        public Guid Guid { get; set; }
        public int SomeTestVal { get; set; }
        public TransactionStatus? TransactionStatus { get; set; }
        public AddressDto Address { get; set; }
        public DetailDto Detail { get; set; }

    }

    public class AddressDto
    {
        public string PostCode1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class DetailDto
    {
        public decimal? LandArea { get; set; }
    }

    public enum TransactionStatus
    {
        Sold = 1,
        ForSale = 2
    }
}
```

Edit:

I have just found that it seems I can do something like this:

in config:

```
        CreateMap<AddressDto, CreatePropertyDataModel>();
        CreateMap<DetailDto, CreatePropertyDataModel>();
        CreateMap<PropertyDto, CreatePropertyDataModel>()
           .ForMember(dest => dest.Guid,
                      opts => opts.MapFrom(
                              src => src.Guid.ToString()));
```

set an object:

```
        var property = new PropertyDto();
        property.Guid = new Guid();//not mapping to guid
        property.SomeTestVal = 123456;
        property.TransactionStatus = TransactionStatus.ForSale;
        property.Address = new AddressDto();
        property.Detail = new DetailDto();
        property.Address.PostCode1 = "ng10";
        property.Detail.LandArea = 12;
        return property;
```

in some class:

```
        var dataModel = new UpsertPropertyDataModel();
        _mapper.Map(_property, dataModel);
        _mapper.Map(_property.Address, dataModel);
        _mapper.Map(_property.Detail, dataModel);
```

My problem with this is that I get the error `Unmapped members were found`, these unmapped members are reffering to members Address or Detail could not map to, so I would have to set those members to `Ignore()`, is this a viable solution that i'm using incorrectly? (please note my real world objects are much bigger)

Comment: Try [this](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/8e15798a8b4facd292feb5fcfbf1e3f7).

Comment: ToString is applied by default, there is no need for MapFrom.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu, thanks for the extension but I can't get it working. My problem is, `using static Expression;` tells me `type or namespace cannot be found`, So I tried `using System.Linq.Expressions; using System.Linq;` but then Iget `the type Flatten does not exist in the namespace extensions` and I can't work out what TSourceMember is or how to use it (I think i'm being really dumb). I have searched for examples in the hope I could convert. But i've had no luck. Could you please provide an example of how to use you extension?

Comment: ```cfg.CreateMap<PropertyDto, FlatProperty>().Flatten(source=>source.Address)```